# MySQL collate clause - before or after the like clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-like, collation

I'm working on moving our DBs from utf8 (utf8mb3) to utf8mb4 (in preparation for eventually moving to MySQL 8), and due to the nature of the system and the number of databases and hosts, I can't do it in one shot. So, I'm trying to figure out if migrating the DBs first (one at a time) before the app would work fine.

While trying it out, I ran into the following situation and wanted to get expert opinion on what's recommended way of doing it and why.

MySQL info:

- version - 5.7.30-33
- innodb_version - 5.7.30-33
- version_comment - Percona Server (GPL), Release 33, Revision 6517692
- character_set_client - utf8
- character_set_connection - utf8
- character_set_database - utf8mb4
- collation_connection - utf8_general_ci
- collation_database - utf8mb4_general_ci

I've a table (*show create table*)

```
CREATE TABLE `mb4table1` (
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

with values

```
mysql> select * from mb4table1;
+------+------+
| name | age  |
+------+------+
| abc  |   43 |
| one  |   41 |
| two  |   42 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With this table and data,
**(1)** if I execute a query

```
mysql> select * from mb4table1 where name like 'Abc';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Of course, it doesn't find any record.
**(2)** If I do this

```
mysql> select * from mb4table1 where name like 'Abc' collate utf8_general_ci;
+------+------+
| name | age  |
+------+------+
| abc  |   43 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

it's able to find the record for *abc*.
**(3)** Whereas, if I move the *collate* clause around,

```
mysql> select * from mb4table1 where name collate utf8_general_ci like 'Abc';
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
```

**(4)** And, if I use a utf8mb4 collation, then it works fine

```
mysql> select * from mb4table1 where name collate utf8mb4_general_ci like 'Abc';
+------+------+
| name | age  |
+------+------+
| abc  |   43 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is, what's the difference between **(2)** and **(3)**? The query **(2)** apparently applied the *collate* clause and returned expected result. And, if I'll have to go with **(3)**, how do I make it work?

Note: The column collation has to stay. Only a couple of queries out of 10s may need to use the collate clause to perform case-insensitive searches.

Comment: 'abc' is an inadequate example -- it is encoded and compared the same way in virtually all character sets and collations.

Comment: At what point to you change the charset and collation associated with the _connections_?  That is what controls the literal `'Abc'`

Comment: @RickJames The connection collation is set while establishing the connection (JDBC connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci)

Comment: That collation implies `charset=utf8`.  Consider changing it when you get to utf8mb4, thereby obviating the need for the collation clause on `LIKE`.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. Since I won't be able to do both the app and the DB at the same time, I've been considering taking this phased approach of migrating the DB first and then updating the app.

Comment: For phasing in, keep this in mind...  The connection parameters state the encoding in the client.  The column definitions state the encoding in the table.  _Those do not have to be the same._  `INSERT` and `SELECT` (etc) will convert (if possible) _as the text flows between the client and database_.

Comment: And...  I am unclear on when _literals_ (eg, 'abc') need conversion.  Another thing that can be done:  `_utf8mb4'abc'` is a way to qualify a literal to have a certain encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the info @RickJames. I'll consider the points you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aslong as mysql doent impemted it and i don't think it is possible anyway

You can check with

```
SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'utf8mb4';
```

Which collations are supported

and at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html you can see all have `utf8mb4_` at the beginning.

If you want go deeper. you can start with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html

```
 'Abc' collate utf8_general_ci
```

That `utf8_general_ci` belongs to the string 'Abc' which has no uf8mb4 (4byte) characters and can be savely converted to that cllation.

```
name collate utf8_general_ci
```

That `utf8_general_ci` belongs to the column name which is uf8mb4 (4byte)  and can **not** be converted ro that collation, because it isn't supported(see above)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. But my question is around why the same utf8 based collation (utf8_general_ci) works fine in (2) but not in (3).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info